# Get Host and port inside an EJB Stateless bean installed in my Websphere server

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, stateless, inetaddress

I have an EJB Stateless Bean that is executed automatically by an Scheduler inside Websphere. My EJB is installed in Websphere. Inside my EJB I would like to make an http request to a webservice exposed by other application (inside de same Server). I tried just using relative path because that is how I usually make requests between applications, but inside my bean I don't know how to get the host name and port to build the URL.

I managed to get the host (ip) by doing this:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();
```

But I also require the port number. The question is: how to get the host and port number of the application server (Websphere) where my EJB application is installed? Is this possible?

This code is how I try to make the request, but this does not work because I need the full path:

```
URL url = new URL("/MyOtherAppName/myservice");         
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
    Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

-edit 1  ----

I think the approach of user **Gas** is nice, and makes my application easier to configure.

I followed this guide to implement the URL Provider approach:

[URL Provider Websphere](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_botzum/0502_botzum.html)

Comment: You know, that for storing just URLs you didn't have to implement URL provider, but just use the `Default URL Provider` that is already there and just add new URL as resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest different approach, rather than getting server host and port use the URL resource and then get it in the EJB. It will be more portable across servers and also more flexible in case you ever move your service somewhere else.

See [Using URL resources within an application](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tjtc_uovr.html?lang=en)

Define URL via console in app server, and use `@Resource` annotation in your EJB like this:

```
@Resource(name="serviceURL", lookup="url/myurl")
URL myURL;
```